# How can I declare a property inside a method?

Tags: php, methods, global-variables

I'm a totally newbie in class writing in PHP, started a couple days ago.

I'd like to declare a new "public property" inside a method to be used in other methods.

This is what I thought (Of course it doesnt' work!):

```
    class hello {

        public function b() {
            public $c = 20; //I'd like to make $c usable by the method output() 
        }

        public function output() {
            echo $c;
        }
    }

$new = new hello;
$new->output();
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Simple, `class hello { public $property; }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'd like to declare a new "public property" inside a method to be used in other methods.

If the other methods are part of the same class, you don't need a public property, a private property will fit your needs. Private properties are accessible within the same class only which helps to keep things simple.

Also understand the difference between *declaring* a property and *assigning* a value to it. Declaring is done when the code is loaded, assigning when it executes. So declaring (or defining) a property (private or public) needs a special place in the PHP syntax, that is in the body of your class and not inside in a function.

You access properties inside the class by using the special variable `$this` in PHP.

> The pseudo-variable *`$this`* is available when a method is called from within an object context. *`$this`* is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs [to]). [*<sup>From PHP Manual</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Private property example:

```
class hello {
    private $c; # properties defined like this have the value NULL by default

    public function b() {
        $this->c = 20; # assign the value 20 to private property $c
    }

    public function output() {
        echo $this->c; # access private property $c
    }
}

$new = new hello;
$new->output(); # NULL
$new->b();
$new->output(); # 20
```

Hope this is helpful. You use a private property because everything else in your program does not need to care about it, so inside your class you know that nothing else can manipulate the value. See as well [Visibility<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Really appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

Every variable of the class is public when you define it inside of a method (function)! You can do this the following way:

```
class hello {

    public function b() {
         $this->c = 20; 
    }

    public function output() {
        echo $this->c;
    }
}

$new = new hello;
$new->output();
```

or let function `b()` return `$c` and then pass it as a variable to `output()`:

```
class hello {

    public function b() {
         return $c = 20; 
    }

    public function output($c) {
        echo $c;
    }
}

$new = new hello;
$c = $new->b();
$new->output($c);
```

Remember all variables inside a function are ONLY accessable from within that particular function...unless you use `$this` of course, which makes the variable a class property!
Also, it's recommended to only `return` variables...echo is only for the real output, the pure HTML, the template, your view, if you know what I mean :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
class hello {

    public $c = null;

    public function b() {
        $this->c = 20; //I'd like to make $c usable by the method output() 
    }

    public function output() {
        echo $this->c;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to set it to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class hello {
    public $c;
    public function b() {
        $this->c = 20;
    }

    public function output() {
        $this->c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** If you need to use a property in another method you don't need to declare that method as public, you should declare the property as private, and you'll have access to your property with no problem:

```
class hello {  
    private $c;  
    public function b() {  
        $this->c = 20;  
    }  
    public function output() {
        $this->c;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class hello {
 public $c;
        public function b() {
            $this->c = 20; //I'd like to make $c usable by the method output() 
        }

        public function output() {
            return $this->c;
        }
    }
$new = new hello;
echo $new->output();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class hello {
        var $c;

        function __construct() { // __construct is called when creating a new instance
            $this->c = 20;
        }

        public function getC() {
            return $this->c; 
            // beter to return a value this way you can later decide what to do with the value without modifying the class
        }
    }

$new = new hello; // create new instance and thus call __construct().
echo $new->getC(); // echo the value
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this code like this :-

```
  class hello {

       public $c;
        public function b() {
            public $this->c = 20; //I'd like to make $c usable by the method output() 
        }

        public function output() {
            echo $this->c;
        }
    }

$new = new hello;
$new->output();
```

Comment: this won't work! function b is never called so the output will be NULL